# What value does the specific humidity obtain when all the mass being considered is water vapor?

Tags: thermodynamics, simulations

I am working on creating a dynamic model of a condenser for a steam turbine and was entertaining the idea of using specific humidity to determine the point at which the steam condenses,

$$\omega = \frac{m_v}{m_a} = 0.622\frac{P_v}{P_a}$$

However, from what I have been told by the power plant engineer, steam leaving the low-pressure (LP) turbine exhaust and into the condenser inlet is pure vapor. How am I able to obtain a value for the specific humidity for $m_a=0$?

Is specific humidity only valid for air/vapor mixtures? Please correct my understanding if it is faulty.

Thank you.

Comment: If there is no air, then specific humidity is meaningless.

Comment: Chet Miller's comment is correct. You need to look at the thermodynamics. The water vapor will condense when its pressure increases above the vapor pressure (for whatever temperature it is at).